# Magento 2 Products 404

Tags: magento2, product, search

Every one of my products 404 when i try using the SEO rewrite link, also when i direct link to the product page it 404's, my search as well doesn't work (which is probably is cause of this). I have read about every Magento Stack issue and each one that is suggested doesnt work for me.

What I've done so far.

Products
  They are enabled, quantity over 0, in stock, Visibility (Catalog,Search), Product in website (main website).

I have reindexed (all indexes are current to date), flushed cache, setup:upgrade, di:compile a bunch of times.

I have checked the sequence_product table each of my id's on in there

In configuration catelog search engine opt the product and category url suffix is blank and i have refreshed the cache.

I may be missing something since I feel I have tried everything.

Not sure exactly what else to do I would appreciate any suggestions.

Please dont mark this a duplicate since I have tried each 404 magento product question and they do not work for me. Dont have enought rep to comment on those posts.

Thanks Magento Community.

Best,

Comment: what about your cms / static pages, category pages ? do they all produce same 404 page

Comment: so my static pages do show i have a few custom modules that show up ok, my category pages also show up however it doesnt not show the products in that category. Which i assume tied to my products 404 issue

Comment: try to reindex with **bin/magento indexer:reindex**

Comment: Done reindexing multiple, multiple times no luck lol.

Comment: Any more thoughs @NaveedAsim?